# How to add item in contact custom facet List type property

Tags: experience-analytics, sitecore-api, xconnect, contact-facets, tracking

I have created a custom facet model with **Sitecore 9.0.1** & **xConnect**.

My contact custom facet contains a property of `List<string>` which I want to populate with different values while contact visiting the site.

*N.B. I have indexed the anonymous contacts.*

I am trying to save the new item in the list using `contact.SetFacet<MyCustomFacet>...`and then adding item to facet, but the problem is the list becomes empty again when I use `contact.GetFacet<MyCustomFacet>...`.

I am submitting the client each time after adding a item. Do I really need that? or, will it automatically saved at session end? I am looking for right way to achieve that.

I want to keep all the items I added to the list available till the session end so that I can use them whenever needed.

```
public static void AddDynamicFacetItem(DynamicFacetItem facetData)
{
    var manager = AnalyticsHelpers.GetContactManager();

    if (manager != null)
    {
        using (var client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var item = facetData.ConvertToData();

                if (AnalyticsHelpers.CurrentTracker.Contact.IsNew)
                {
                    Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactSaveMode = ContactSaveMode.AlwaysSave;
                    manager.SaveContactToCollectionDb(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact);

                    var trackerIdentifier = new IdentifiedContactReference(
                        Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Constants.IdentifierSource,
                        Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId.ToString("N"));

                    var contact = client.Get<Contact>(trackerIdentifier,
                        new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactExpandOptions());

                    AddItemForNewContact(client, contact, item);
                }
                else
                {
                    var trackerIdentifier = new IdentifiedContactReference(
                        Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Constants.IdentifierSource,
                        Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId.ToString("N"));

                    var contact = client.Get<Contact>(trackerIdentifier,
                        new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactExpandOptions(DynamicDataFacet.DefaultFacetKey));

                    AddItemForExistingContact(client, contact, item);
                }

                manager.RemoveFromSession(AnalyticsHelpers.CurrentTracker.Contact.ContactId);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error(e.Message, e, "AddDynamicFacetItem");
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void AddItemForNewContact(XConnectClient client, Sitecore.XConnect.Contact contact,
    XYZ.Model.Data data)
{
    try
    {
        if (contact != null)
        {
            var list = new List<Data> { data };

            client.SetFacet<DynamicDataFacet>(contact, DynamicDataFacet.DefaultFacetKey, new DynamicDataFacet()
            {
                Data = list
            });

            client.Submit();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error(e.Message, e, "AddItemForNewContact");
    }
}

private static void AddItemForExistingContact(XConnectClient client, Sitecore.XConnect.Contact contact,
    XYZ.Model.Data data)
{
    try
    {
        if (contact != null)
        {
            if (contact.DynamicData() != null)
            {
                contact.DynamicData().Data.Add(data);
            }
            else
            {
                var list = new List<Data> { data };

                client.SetFacet<DynamicDataFacet>(contact, DynamicDataFacet.DefaultFacetKey,
                    new DynamicDataFacet()
                    {
                        Data = list
                    });
            }

            client.Submit();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error(e.Message, e, "AddItemForExistingContact");
    }
}
```

[xdb_collection].ContactFacets data:

```
2DBF166D-45E5-0000-0000-0539A599359D    DynamicData 2018-03-16 11:30:16.5605749 C8032A2E-C837-4FA1-B150-B559EFE237DD    {"@odata.type":"#xyz.Model.DynamicDataFacet","Data":[{"PropertyName":"Discount.Amount","Type":"System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","Value":"1520"}]}
```

JSON:

```
{
  "Name": "XYZ.Model.DynamicDataModel",
  "Version": "1.0",
  "References": [
    {
      "Name": "XConnect",
      "Version": "1.0"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model",
      "Version": "9.0"
    }
  ],
  "Types": {
    "XYZ.Model.DynamicDataFacet": {
      "Type": "Facet",
      "BaseType": "Sitecore.XConnect.Facet",
      "ClrType": "XYZ.Model.DynamicDataFacet, XYZ, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
      "Properties": {
        "Data": {
          "Type": [
            "XYZ.Model.Data"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "XYZ.Model.Data": {
      "Type": "Complex",
      "ClrType": "XYZ.Model.Data, XYZ, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
      "Properties": {
        "PropertyName": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "Type": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "Value": {
          "Type": "String"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Facets": [
    {
      "Target": "Contact",
      "Name": "DynamicData",
      "Type": "XYZ.Model.DynamicDataFacet"
    }
  ]
}
```

Model

```
namespace XYZ.Model
{
    [Serializable]
    [FacetKey(DefaultFacetKey)]
    public class DynamicDataFacet : Facet
    {
        public const string DefaultFacetKey = "DynamicData";
        public List<Data> Data { get; set; }

        public DynamicDataFacet()
        {
            Data = new List<Data>();
        }
    }
}

namespace XYZ.Model
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Data
    {
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace XYZ.Model
{
    public class DynamicDataModel
    {
        public static XdbModel Model { get; } = BuildModel();

        private static XdbModel BuildModel()
        {
            XdbModelBuilder modelBuilder = new XdbModelBuilder("XYZ.Model.DynamicDataModel", new XdbModelVersion(1, 0));
            modelBuilder.ReferenceModel(Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.CollectionModel.Model);
            modelBuilder.DefineFacet<Contact, DynamicDataFacet>(DynamicDataFacet.DefaultFacetKey);
            return modelBuilder.BuildModel();
        }
    }
}

public static DynamicDataFacet DynamicData(this Contact contact)
        {
            return contact.GetFacet<DynamicDataFacet>(DynamicDataFacet.DefaultFacetKey);
        }
```

Comment: Add more code samples especially how are you prepare data and then set facet. That is not clear from current samples

Comment: Do you use 'new ContactExpandOptions(MyCustomFacet)' when getting Contact ? This could be one reason

Comment: Yes I used ContactExpandOptions with Custom facet key.

Comment: Have you verified that the facets are saved? Take a look in ContactFacets table in one of Shard dbs

Comment: I verified the Shard0 and Shard1 db. Custom facet get saved but list propery is always empty. But I will update my question with code sample soon. Hope that will help

Comment: Add also screenshot or value from table from Shard dbs to verify whether it is saved correctly

Comment: @chorpo I have added code samples. Please have a look

Comment: Can you add your contact facet model code and JSON?

Comment: @pete-navarra please check the code.

Comment: @enthusiast - as Pete mentioned, put in question also contact facet model code. That is missing.

Comment: @pete-navarra code updated

Comment: @enthusiast - Is `DynamicData()` an extension method on the contact, and if so, can you post that code?

Comment: What is AnalyticsHelpers.GetContactManager() doing?  Also, is this code executed on the CD's or on the CM's?  when is this code executed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use similar code as below one to fix your problems to get and set custom facet values:

```
Contact contact = client.Get<Contact>(
   new IdentifiedContactReference(_contactSource, contactIdentifier),
   new ContactExpandOptions(DynamicDataFacet.DefaultFacetKey));

var list = new List<Data> { data };

if (contact != null)
{
  var facet = contact.GetFacet<DynamicDataFacet>(DynamicDataFacet.DefaultFacetKey);

  if (facet != null)
  {
     facet.DynamicDataFacet.Add(new DynamicDataFacet()
       { Data = list }));

     client.SetFacet(contact, DynamicDataFacet.DefaultFacetKey, facet);
  }
  else
  {
     client.SetFacet(contact, DynamicDataFacet.DefaultFacetKey, new DynamicDataFacet() { Data = list }));
  }
}
```

We have similar code in production but I have changed facet names to correspond yours.

I think you have three issues in your code that cause you trouble:

**1)**

You should use `client.GetFacet` instead of `contact.DynamicData() != null`.

Also `client.SetFacet` should be used instead of `contact.DynamicData().Data.Add` as I think `contact.DynamicData().Data.Add` will do nothing at all at the end. 
You are adding something to `contact` but `client` object doesn't know about that when you are calling `client.Submit()` here in your code below (look in my suggested code above to compare):

```
if (contact != null)
    {
        if (contact.DynamicData() != null)
        {
            contact.DynamicData().Data.Add(data);
        }
        else
        {
            var list = new List<Data> { data };

            client.SetFacet<DynamicDataFacet>(contact, DynamicDataFacet.DefaultFacetKey,
                new DynamicDataFacet()
                {
                    Data = list
                });
        }

        client.Submit();
```

**2)**

You should not use `new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactExpandOptions())`.

You should always use `new ContactExpandOptions(DynamicDataFacet.DefaultFacetKey)` instead in your case.

**3)**

Not related to your issue directly but you should have only one method to set facet not two as you have now. :)

Also you are repeating code here:

```
var trackerIdentifier = new IdentifiedContactReference(
Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Constants.IdentifierSource,
Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId.ToString("N"));

var contact = client.Get<Contact>(trackerIdentifier,
                    new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactExpandOptions());
```

That should be moved to unified AddItem method.

Follow DRY principles!

More information about facets on contacts in xConnect:

- [xConnect doc site for getting/setting facets](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-client-api/contacts/get-contacts/get-facets.html)

Comment: I spent a fair amount of time, with the time that I had working on a solution and then saw this answer and realized that it was exactly what I had found.  This is the right answer.

Comment: I made the required changes, but could not verify the result. I will give my feedback on my next working day. Thanks for your support guys.

Comment: Keeping fingers crossed and keep us posted :)

Comment: Great @Enthusiast :) Glad to be able to help